# TcpConnection wrapped interceptor publish TcpConnectionOpenEvent whose connection factory property is unknown

Tags: java, spring, tcp, spring-integration

I created a small Tcp communication application linked below.

[si_tcp_sample](https://github.com/neriudon/si_tcp_sample)

It is based on [TCP Sample in spring-integration-samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/tcp-client-server). The message generated by the Gateway is sent over TCP by the Outbound Gateway to the Inbound Channel Adapter. In turn the Outbound Channel Adapter echo response comes back over TCP. This application has two TcpNetClientConnectionFactories, the one is set a interceptor factory chain and another is not. 
Running this application, the log like below is outputted.

```
TcpConnectionOpenEvent with TcpConnection wrapped Interceptor↓
16:50:01.411 [main] DEBUG com.neriudon.example.tcp.listener.TcpConnectionEventsListener - ★OPEN★ TcpConnectionOpenEvent [source=SimpleInterceptor:null], [factory=unknown, connectionId=localhost:50001:64609:627f6eb5-401f-44e2-88a9-4f966ee66092] **OPENED** 

TcpConnectionOpenEvent with raw TcpConnection↓
16:50:01.426 [main] DEBUG com.neriudon.example.tcp.listener.TcpConnectionEventsListener - ★OPEN★ TcpConnectionOpenEvent [source=TcpNetConnection:localhost:50002:64610:ee9b0bcd-aa9a-4fdb-9194-2e761caabed6], [factory=client2, connectionId=localhost:50002:64610:ee9b0bcd-aa9a-4fdb-9194-2e761caabed6] **OPENED**
```

TcpConnection wrapped interceptor publish TcpConnectionOpenEvent whose connection factory property is "unknown". I think that this connection factory property should be "client1". Is it why?
(The version of Spring Integration is 4.3.12.)

*Editted from here*

Other TcpConnectionEvents' connection factory property seem correct.
For example, TcpConnectionCloseEvent log is below.

```
TcpConnectionCloseEvent with TcpConnection wrapped Interceptor↓
20:26:54.009 [main] DEBUG com.neriudon.example.tcp.listener.TcpConnectionEventsListener - ★CLOSE★ TcpConnectionCloseEvent [source=TcpNetConnection:localhost:50001:53828:ec63181f-3db1-478b-8a38-160a431a8887], [factory=client1, connectionId=localhost:50001:53828:ec63181f-3db1-478b-8a38-160a431a8887] **CLOSED** 

TcpConnectionCloseEvent with raw TcpConnection↓
20:26:54.021 [main] DEBUG com.neriudon.example.tcp.listener.TcpConnectionEventsListener - ★CLOSE★ TcpConnectionCloseEvent [source=TcpNetConnection:localhost:50002:53829:4e02e3cc-7eb8-4e5d-a41a-2e6ff99518aa], [factory=client2, connectionId=localhost:50002:53829:4e02e3cc-7eb8-4e5d-a41a-2e6ff99518aa] **CLOSED**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug; the connection factory name is not propagated to the interceptor.

Please [open a JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT).

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm sorry for late response and thank you for creating the issue.

Comment: I [fixed the  bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/2326). It should be merged this week and we will make a release soon.